# Typescript decorators unexpected behavior

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, typescript-decorator

I have a decorator defined to create routes with express

```
export const Get = (path: string) => {
  return (
    target: any,
    property: string,
    descriptor: PropertyDescriptor
  ): PropertyDescriptor => {
    console.log(`Creating router for get request, path ${path}`);
    if (!Reflect.hasMetadata("routes", target.constructor)) {
      Reflect.defineMetadata("routes", [], target.constructor);
    }
    const routes = Reflect.getMetadata("routes", target.constructor);
    routes.push({
      method: "get",
      path,
      handler: target[property]
    });
    Reflect.defineMetadata("routes", routes, target.constructor);
    return descriptor;
  };
};
```

And a decorator to protect routes

```
export const protect = function(type: authenticatorType = "JWT") {
  const authFactory = AuthFactory.getInstance();
  const authenticator: IAuthenticator = authFactory.getAuthenticator(type);
  return (
    target: any,
    property: string,
    descriptor: PropertyDescriptor
  ): PropertyDescriptor => {
    const method = descriptor.value;
    descriptor.value = function(...args: any[]) {
      const req: Request = args[0];
      const token = <string>req.headers.token;
      if (!token) {
        throw new HTTP401Error();
      }
      const payload = authenticator.verify(token);
      const result = method.apply(this, [...args, payload]);
      return result;
    };
    //Object.defineProperty(target, property, descriptor);
    return descriptor;
  };
};
```

When I try to use `protect` with `Get`, it does not work. To make it work, I have to uncomment `//Object.defineProperty(target, property, descriptor);`. Without that, the decoration code block is not executed at all.
However, if I use it without `Get` it works fine even without using `Object.defineProperty()`.

```
@Controller("/users/:uuid/connections")
export default class ConnectionController {
  constructor() {
    console.debug("Creating network controller");
  }
  @Get("/")
  @protect()
  getConnections(req: Request, res: Response, meta?: any) {
    const s: Social = new Social();
    const result = s.getConnection();
    return res.json(result);
  }
  @Post("/")
  createConnection(req: Request, res: Response) {
    return res.json({ method: "POST" });
  }
  @Put("/:connectionId/status")
  updateConnectionStatus(req: Request, res: Response) {
    const connectionId = req.params.connectionId;
    return res.json({ connectionId });
  }
}
```

I am not able to understand why the behavior differs.

Comment: It helps if your code constitutes a [mcve] where there are no dependencies on code or 3rd-party libraries not presented (unless tagged as such), so someone can see for themselves what's happening.  The only issue in the code should be the one you're trying to solve.  Ideally you'd also provide a link to something like stackblitz or the TypeScript playground.  As it stands, `authenticatorType`, `AuthFactory`, `IAuthenticator`, `Controller`, etc are unavailable if I try to paste that code into my IDE.  Good luck!

Comment: Most of them have a minimal implementation, as I am just starting with typescript. You can check the source code here https://github.com/Krrish-raj/firefly

Comment: Unfortunately I’m not going to be able to spend more time on this without a [mcve] in the question itself.  To be clear: “minimum” implies that any code not directly related to the issue should be removed; “reproducible” means that others can easily run the code and see what the issue is.  In my tests I saw both decorators run, so I can’t reproduce. I know it’s more effort to produce a minimum reproducible example, but without one it is significantly less probable that you will get a meaningful answer.  Good luck again!